# Windows 8 App and access to file system

Tags: c#, windows-8, file-access

I'm at the beginning of my project and I wonder which technology I should use.
In my little research I found WinRT API being kind of pleasant and I really like tile grid concept in UI.

The only problem is that my app will generate tons of data - important data - which I have to store somewhere on the local machine. By 'somewhere' I mean use of a different partition than the OS.

So, why not to try this simple code.

```
await Windows.Storage.PathIO.WriteTextAsync(@"d:\tests\test.txt", "Hello World");
```

Because `E_ACCESSDENIED`, that's why. Windows 8 slaps me in face screaming "Access Denied".

Is there any way I can store my data in a way I like or `Win8` is too `h4x0r` proof?

And no, "Make a desktop application" is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know about [file access and permissions in Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. But what when Windows will crash? All the files are on system partition - `Application install directory`, `Application data locations` - and all those locations will be wiped out when sysadmin will do recovery.

Comment: You can't do amything about wiping data if you do a recovery, and that is a good thing.  If your app suddenly uses up all my available space I want to blast away all data if I remove your app.  A developer simply does not (and *should not*) have the right to say "Hey, my data is important so don't remove it.  Ever!"  Same goes for a system recovery.  It's the user's machine, not the developer's.

Comment: It is industrial automation. This data is used to generate reports.
That's why I want it on the other partition, so sysadmin could wipe out OS partition during restore.
Sure I can keep data on main server - and I do - but connection to a server is slow - and that's why data is being cached on operators machine.
I have my answer for my boss: "I can't do telemetry app in Windows 8 style". It is simple and clear :)

Answer (score 3):

**First of all, when storing config data you have two options:**

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
```

Which will use the roaming profile space so it will be stored in Cloud or Domain Profile

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Which will use the local profile space

Of course they both will be stored in the end under your users %appdata% but the roaming one will actually be synched if I understand everything correctly :)

**So, for the application data that you would like to store on another partition:**

First you need to select the location by using a FolderPicker

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
//Add some other yada yada to make the picker work as needed
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

Then you need to put the selected folder in an access list to remember that it's allowed to use this folder

```
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
```

That way the application / system will keep track that it's allowed to use this folder in the future. The selected folder could be anywhere in the file system where you have access.

Finally if you wan't to get the selected folder back next time the app starts you simply do the opposite:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("TargetFolderToken",AccessCacheOptions.FastLocationsOnly);
```

The value FastLocationsOnly means that it will only return local drives. "TargetFolderToken" is the same identifier you used when you stored the folder in the FutureAccessList.