# Search for files in machine in metro app using C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML,As we all know we can search music files in music library using below code.

```
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> itemsList  = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetItemsAsync();
```

What about music files in other drives(partitions) like `D:`,`E:` etc..Is there any way to search other drives for music files?
**Brief:** I want to search `.mp3` files from my hard-drive and display them in Gridview, is there any efficient way to achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s possible to search within other folders or drives, but it´s required to use the FolderPicker to select the StorageFolder...

```
async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> FindMusicFiles()
{
    var folderPicker = new FolderPicker()
    {
        CommitButtonText = "Yippie!",
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder,
        ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List
    };

    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (folder != null)
    {
       StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = folder.CreateFileQuery();
       queryResult.ApplyNewQueryOptions(new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, new[] { ".mp3" }));
       IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
       return files;
    }

    return new StorageFile[] { };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps are restricted to search within KnownFolders or LocalFolder of the application, so you cannot search within other drives

Comment: Thank you Zubair, Small doubt, We can get files by using FolderPicker, For the first time i can use FolderPicker to get files and when app launches second time can we get files from that path automatically.

Comment: Not totally sure what you are trying to say, let me give that a try

Comment: Sorry for not being accurate, If i have path(E:\Mymusic), can we retrieve files from folder(Mymusic) without using FolderPicker.

Comment: No you cant, it is not permitted in Windows Store apps

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible for the app to remember the folder(s) you've selected with the FolderPicker, see my post on [Windows 8 App and access to file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266423/windows-8-app-and-access-to-file-system) where I've explained how to use FutureAccessList...